# How to create a plugin for chrome so that it can read the web page's text and send it to python program? 

Tags: python, google-chrome-extension

I have a program written for text simplification in python language, I need this program to be run on a browser as a plugin... If you click the plugin it should take the webpage's text as input and pass this input to my text simplification program and the output of the program should be again displayed in another web page...

Text simplification program takes input text and produces a simplified version of the text, so now I'm planning to create a plugin which uses this program and produces simplified version of text on the webpage...

It will be of great help if anyone help me out through this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use NPAPI plugins in Chrome Extension:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html

Then you use [Content Scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) to get the webpage text, you pass it to the [Background Page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html) via [Messaging](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html). Then your NPAPI plugin will call python (do it however you like since its all in C++), and from the Background Page, you send the text within the plugin.

Concerning your NPAPI plugin, you can take a look how it is done in [pyplugin](http://pyplugin.com/) or gather ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101225/problems-calling-python-from-c) to create it.

Now the serious question, why can't you do this all in JavaScript?

Comment: I have done my text simplification project in python language it will be really hard on me to recreate it again on Js, i want the same python return program to do the work of converting and JS to carry out extension work..

Comment: To talk to anything but web technologies (html + js + css) you must use NPAPI plugins

Comment: In your NPAPI (C++) You can call your python module by importing python.h and PyImport_ImportModule

Comment: hey sorry.. i'm not able to understand can u pls explain little more about ur last post..

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101225/problems-calling-python-from-c and that is how they run a python file from C++. Then you can bundle that C++ code into a plugin by following the NPAPI interface.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an easier way than trying to figure out plugins, make it run as a webservice somewhere (Google App Engine is good for Python, and free), then use a bookmarklet to send pages from the browser. As an added bonus, it works with any browser, not just Chrome.

**More explanation:**
Rather than running on your own computer, you make your program run on a computer at Google (or somewhere else), and access it over the web. See [Google's introduction to App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/introduction.html). Then, if you want it in your browser, you make a "bookmarklet" - a little bit of javascript that grabs the web page you're currently on (either the code or the URL, depends on what you're trying to do), and sends it to your program over the web. You can add this to your browser's bookmark bar as a button you can click. There's some more info on [this site](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-make-a-bookmarklet-for-your-web-application/).

Comment: can u explain more... i'm not getting your idea.. How can i run program over google app engine if you could send some links it will very great full :)

Comment: @Bhuvan: You're welcome. If it's helped you, feel free to accept the answer by clicking the tick symbol on the left.

Comment: sure. i'm going through ur suggestion, will get back to you soon thanks :)